# How can I combine data from the same table that has a different flag?

Tags: sql, pervasive

I'm trying to pull data that contains a job number, order number, part number and description. Some rows in my table are flagged as 'L' for Labor and 'M' for Material. L flagged rows can be taken literally, hours_worked = total hours on job, labor = cost of labor, overhead = cost of overhead. M flagged rows are different, hours_worked = quantity purchased and amount_labor = purchase price of material. How can I differentiate between these two flags and print it into the same table?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
DETAIL.JOB, 
DETAIL.SUFFIX, 
ORDER.ORDER_NO, 
ORDER.ORDER_LINE,
ORDER.PART,
DETAIL.SEQ, 
OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION,
SUM(lbr.Hours) AS sum_hours,
SUM(lbr.Labor) AS sum_labor,
SUM(lbr.Overhead) AS sum_overhead, 
SUM(mtl.Qty) AS sum_qty,
SUM(mtl.material) AS sum_mtl
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    DETAIL.HOURS_WORKED AS Hours,
    DETAIL.AMOUNT_LABOR AS Labor,
    DETAIL.AMT_OVERHEAD AS Overhead
    FROM
    GT.DETAIL DETAIL
    WHERE
    DETAIL.LMO = 'L') AS lbr,
    (SELECT
    DETAIL.HOURS_WORKED AS Qty,
    DETAIL.AMOUNT_LABOR AS Material
    FROM
    GT.DETAIL DETAIL
    WHERE
    DETAIL.LMO = 'M') AS mtl,
GT.DETAIL DETAIL,
GT.OPERATIONS OPERATIONS, 
GT.ORDER ORDER  
WHERE 
ORDER.JOB = DETAIL.JOB AND
ORDER.SUFFIX = DETAIL.SUFFIX AND
DETAIL.JOB = OPERATIONS.JOB AND
DETAIL.SEQ = OPERATIONS.SEQ AND
DETAIL.SUFFIX = OPERATIONS.SUFFIX
GROUP BY
DETAIL.JOB, 
DETAIL.SUFFIX, 
ORDER.ORDER_NO, 
ORDER.ORDER_LINE,
ORDER.PART,
DETAIL.SEQ, 
OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION
```

Every time I run the above, it runs forever and eventually crashes. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has known LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN syntax for some time now. Even when using a database like `Pervasive` you can use that kind of JOINs too (More info: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins))

I tried to do a re-write of your query, using INNER JOINs.

```
SELECT 
   DETAIL.JOB, 
   DETAIL.SUFFIX, 
   ORDER.ORDER_NO, 
   ORDER.ORDER_LINE,
   ORDER.PART,
   DETAIL.SEQ, 
   OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION,
   SUM(CASE WHEN LMO='L' THEN DETAIL.Hours END) AS sum_hours,
   SUM(CASE WHEN LMO='L' THEN DETAIL.Labor END) AS sum_labor,
   SUM(CASE WHEN LMO='L' THEN DETAIL.Overhead END) AS sum_overhead, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN LMO='M' THEN DETAIL.Qty END) AS sum_qty,
   SUM(CASE WHEN LMO='M' THEN DETAIL.material END) AS sum_mtl
FROM
   GT.DETAIL DETAIL
INNER JOIN GT.OPERATIONS OPERATIONS ON OPERATIONS.JOB = DETAIL.JOB 
                                   AND OPERATIONS.SEQ = DETAIL.SEQ 
                                   AND OPERATIONS.SUFFIX = DETAIL.SUFFIX
INNER JOIN GT.ORDER ORDER ON ORDER.JOB = DETAIL.JOB
                         AND ORDER.SUFFIX = DETAIL.SUFFIX

WHERE
   GT.DETAIL.LMO IN ('L','M')

GROUP BY
   DETAIL.JOB, 
   DETAIL.SUFFIX, 
   ORDER.ORDER_NO, 
   ORDER.ORDER_LINE,
   ORDER.PART,
   DETAIL.SEQ, 
   OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION
```

The [CASE WHEN](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.CASE_(expression).htm) is added to the `SUM()` to make the correct calculations.

I am not sure if you need `WHERE GT.DETAIL.LMO IN ('L','M')`. When you have other values for `LMO` then `L` and/or `M` which need to be selected too, you should remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jakkej14:  Can you tell if this helped, or if there was a problem with this ?

Comment: @jakkej14  I would be happy to know when my answer is not correct...  But no reaction....